# How to find DB entry from alpha numeric string in url

Tags: url

Currently I am showing posts on my website Url with their database id

www.mywebsite.com/128

Alot of sites use an alpha numeric string instead

https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7vQd.png

what is this called and how do i generate it and the decode it so i can find my db entry.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I was after.  It will hash the id and you can display that as part of your url.  When you read it you can use the function to convert the hash back to the original id
http://www.hashids.org/php/